# Visualizing/plotting location based on accelerometer/gyro readings over time

Tags: iphone, coordinates, accelerometer, plot, spatial

What's the easiest way to plot location track based on series of reading of accelerometer/gyro/compass sensors taken over time? Let's say I have following data taken every second:

ElapsedTime(s) xMag(uT) yMag(uT) zMag(uT) xAccel(g) yAccel(g) zAccel(g) xRate(rad/sec) yRate(rad/sec) zRate(rad/sec) roll(rad) pitch(rad) yaw(rad)
...

Is there an easy way to draw a location plot for any given time? I'm using iPhone 4 with xSensor app to capture data, but can't just use GPS. I would appreciate any hints. Both standalone applications and Java libraries would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double integration of the acceleration vector (after gyro & compass direction correction) will give you a location from some initial or arbitrary offset.  The problem is that any small offset or errors in the acceleration data, which there will be, will result in a rapidly diverging position.

What might be more possible is to get frequent and precise GPS position data, and use the acceleration data to estimate the route in between two very nearby GPS fixes.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know that mathematically acceleration is the second derivative of location so double integration should give a position but I was looking for a more practical answer of how to do that. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use GPS as measurements conducted underwater

Comment: Precise underwater location is generally found by sonar positioning techniques, distance from 3 pingers with known positions for instance.  There should be some declassified papers on the DSP and hydroacoustics/physics required for this type of solution.  Again, you might be able to use sensor fusion of accelerometer data for very short term position interpolations between sonar position readings.  But I'm not sure how to get sound into an iPhone underwater...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware about sonar positioning. This is not what I'm trying to do. I guess more general question would be: is it feasible to plot (approximate) location chart based on the input from sensors outlined in original question :)

Comment: @maximdim, for a very short period of time (maybe on the order of a second or so), possibly yes.  Anything much longer without an anchor reference to remove varying offsets, and your position error will rapidly run off at a quadratically increasing rate until it diverges right off the planet.

Comment: @hotpaw2: Thanks. That's just too bad. Was hoping to visualize my scuba dives with the scooter :\

Comment: @maxindim, Don't they make little GPS floaters you can drag around above your dive?

Comment: @hotpaw2 they probably do but it's a nuisance to drag and also safety hazard (line entanglement, boats, etc) plus it won't record your depth and because of the currents surface position could be way off. Would be much better place some device inside scooter but GPS obviously can't be used underwater. Oh well.